# Why does the oozie launcher consume 2 yarn containers?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am using Oozie to execute a spark job.

I "kind-of" understand that oozie lunches a map-only mapreduce job and from there lunches the spark-job.

What I do not understand is why this job consumes 2 yarn-containers?

In Yarn's resource manager page (titled "All Applications") I see something like this:

ID: application_nnnnn_3456
Name: oozie: launcher...
Application Type: MAPREDUCE
Running Containers: **2**

ID: application_nnnnn_3457
Name: spark-app
Application Type: SPARK
Running Containers: **1**

Is the oozie-launcher hosting 2 **yarn application masters**?   One for the MAPREDUCE job and one for Spark job?

Comment: Possible scenario: the Oozie "launcher" job runs in 1 pseudo-Mapper **plus the mandatory YARN Application Master** for a total of 2 containers; the "launcher" runs the Spark driver, in YARN-client mode, but without any executor because your code does not require it (or your code is not distributable) so you just see the -- idle -- YARN AM

Comment: Note that with a Cloudera distro, by default, Oozie runs the "launcher" inside the AM container, so there would be only 1 YARN container; but with a Horton distro the "launcher" is distinct, which means 2 containers. Therefore I assume you don't run a Cloudera distro...

Comment: I am running cloudera...so are we saying that there is one container for the luncher & one container for the application master.  now the question is...is this application master housing the luncher?  I think the answer is yes.  Because the saprk-application will have it is own application master?  Does that make sense?

Comment: To be sure, just inspect the YARN status while the job is running: application => app attempt #1 with AM listed explicitly => list of containers, AM as _00001, workers with higher indices // then after completion open the YARN logs (per container) -- the AM logs are about allocating the other containers, and the Oozie launcher is veeeeery verbose about the CLASSPATH and stuff like that in StdOut (plus the Spark driver logs)

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter! I'll try this experiment.  If you like put down an answer and I'll accept it.