# Run single application master for oozie workflow

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, oozie, bigdata

(according to [Why does the oozie luncher consume 2 yarn containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172110/why-does-the-oozie-luncher-consume-2-yarn-containers))

I have cluster with 1900 core and 11TB RAM.
And I have next structure of workflow for my Oozie WF:

- Approximately 300-400 subworkflows with same structure that will run
  in parallel (by fork control node)
- In these subflows one-by-one run
  several tasks (java actions, spark tasks, shell actions)
- Some of
  subflows can execute in 3-5 minutes, some of them - 2-3 hours (long
  term spark tasks)

The question is - is it possible to run these subworkflows in a ***single*** container (application master)? By default, for each subworkflow oozie/yarn uses two cores: one for AM and one for map-reduce task (controller). And this is the bottleneck - 1/3 of all cores of my cluster used only for controlling but not for computing

Comment: *"1/3 of all cores"* -- I guess you you mean the logical "vcores" allocated by YARN, not the real CPU cores. If your cluster runs at "full load" but the real CPU usage is low, then you may want to overallocate -- cf. https://hortonworks.com/blog/managing-cpu-resources-in-your-hadoop-yarn-clusters/ _"...Number of vcores has to be set by an administrator ... The general recommendation is to set it to the number of physical cores on the node, but administrators can bump it up if they wish to run additional containers on nodes with faster CPUs ..."_ --  or if they have lots of AM containers.

Comment: yep, I mean vCores, not real CPUs

Comment: I would also recommend to keep an eye on the Oozie on Yarn feature (OOZIE-1770).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can use the uber mode of the oozie to save the container which launches the oozie action job. The AM will launch the action instead of doing it from a separate container.

Add the following property into `oozie-site.xml`.

```
<property>
  <name>oozie.action.launcher.mapreduce.job.ubertask.enable</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```